$f$ is continuous then if $\int_0^\infty |f(x)| \, dx$ converges, $\int_0^\infty f^2(x) \, dx$ does not always converges.
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Is it true that if $\int_0^\infty |f(x)| \, dx$ converges, then $\int_0^\infty f^2(x) \, dx$  can diverge?
I did manage to find a counter example for this question which is the following:

you can ignore the [$2\pi k$,$2\pi k +\pi$] interval (that was related to a different question). the counter example is essentially Trapezoids that are going to became taller but thinner at the same time.Let $T_k$ be the trapezoid with bases of length $\frac{4}{3k^3}$ and  $\frac{2}{3k^3}$ and height k so its area will be is $\frac{1}{k^2}$ thus we get the following:

note that for the squared function I am taking only parts of the new trapezoids (the height is now $k^2$ and taking the smaller base of the previous trapezoids which is now a sum of rectangles which are smaller).
So this example is a counter-example for the question, but I was wondering if there are other functions that have this property which are not so constructed (meaning not  trapezoids functions or triangles or any of these) I want to know if there are more "elementary functions" like this. Much help would be very much appreciated!

$f(x)={1\over \sqrt{|x|}+x^2}$

not continuous on R

My bad. In order to avoid cases I would try $f(x)=g(x)\sin^2(h(x))$ for some $g$ and $h$ defined by formulas not requeiring cases.

umm, how did you come up with that? what is the motivation and what kind of g and h could satisfy the question?

$f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{3}{4}}} \sin(x^2)$
I think this might work

I don't think so as for $x\ge 1$ $f^2\le |f|.$

A choice of $|f|$ with a peak of $O(n^a)$ height and $O(n^{-b})$ width for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and negligible other area for $|f|$ and $f^2$, works if $a<b-1<2a$. The choice $f=(1+x^2)^c\cos^2(\pi x^d)$ has such a peak at $x=n^{1/d}$, viz. $a=2c/d$ and $b=d-1$.

I don't think I understand what you wrote down, could you elaborate on that please?
